# Using facebook graph API to fetch app users returns only the test users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm using the `Facebook Graph API` Explorer to fetch all of my friends that are using my app. I am trying to do it with graph API:

`me/friends?fields=id,installed,name`

or

FQL: `SELECT uid, name, pic FROM user WHERE is_app_user AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`

and in both ways I only get the test users although I definitely have friends that using my app. The app is not in development mode and public. What is going on?

Comment: Is the your app status live and available to all users??

Comment: Yes. Users are authenticated by the app.

Comment: FB.api('me/friends?fields=id,installed,name', function(response) 
{console.log(response);}   
What response you are getting. Is there any errors coming.

Comment: No error. I get a list of my friends that use my app but the only problem is that I only get the testers (friends that are defined as testers) and not the rest.

Comment: That is by design. In Facebook API v2.0 you only get friends that have installed the app.

Comment: OK so first I didn't ask about fetching all the friend list but only the friends that are using my app. I said that the problem is that I only get the testers users. I found the solution for this and it's because the app didn't asked for user_friends permission in the authentication. Secondly, how can I fetch all of the user's friends in API v2.0?

Comment: I now understand that you cannot do it in API v2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this and it's because the app didn't asked for user_friends permission in the authentication.

Comment: when you were in the development mode, can you get the list of your friends who are using your app?  I can't seem to be able to do it...

Comment: Make sure you are asking for the 'user_friends' permission in the app settings